# Handle Gmail (Send/Receive) in Win Forms

Tags: c#, gmail

For certain reasons I want to develop Gmail desktop application for my self
in C#. So that I can retrieve email (including attachments)
(I dont want to use outlook/thunderbird etc. clients for desktop)

So please suggest what is better option, so far I have got following two
where I can start:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name

https://gmailerxp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try *DevMvcComponent 3.0*

```
Install-Package DevMVCComponent
```

use this readme at https://github.com/aukgit/DevMvcComponent.

```
var gmailServer = new GmailServer("you@gmail.com", "password");
gmailer.QuickSend("sendingto@gmail.com", "Subject", "HTML body");
```

You are good to go then.

Answer (score 0):

```
Install-Package OpenPop.NET
```

Take a look of OpenPop.NET: https://github.com/foens/hpop

```
using (var client = new Pop3Client())
{
    client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, useSsl: true,
        receiveTimeout: 30 * 1000, sendTimeout: 60 * 1000,
        certificateValidator: null);

    client.Authenticate("username", "password");

    var messageUids = client.GetMessageUids();
    foreach (var messageUid : messageUids)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received email: " + messageUid);
    }
}
```

You have to lower your account security if using custom-made programs.
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en